# algorithm of finding RUNTIME_FUNCTION in a x64 stack

Tags: c++, windows, 64-bit, stack-unwinding

I'm trying to unwind a x64 stack.
In order to do so I need to follow this algorithm specified here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ydc79k6.aspx

But in order to follow it, I need to know how to find the correct `RUNTIME_FUNCTION`, but I couldn't find a complete algorithm for this...

does anybody know how to do it? (A link or example will be also really appreciated)

Comment: my bet is that this is related to the MS [PE binary format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable). You should look into the docs linked at the end of the wikipedia article.

Answer (score 0):

Are you opposed to calling an API to do this? [RtlLookupFunctionEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will do it for you.